# Text moves under different resolutions

Tags: css

http://rssreaderbg.net/pubsubbub/example/cssexam/index.php
Click on the clover.After the animation text shows.
On bigger resolutions text changes his position.It because 
`position: absolute; top: 35px; left: 400px;`
But I don't know how to position it in another way.
If I set some margins or paddings ,whole page moves down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `position: absolute;` referencing the body (i.e. you havn't set it anywhere else)

If you put

```
position: relative;
```

on your header in the CSS, it should make the position absolute relative to that div, so resizing the window won't move the text.

```
#header {
    background: url("headers.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: relative; /*add this line in*/
    height: 139px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
}
```